# Add parameters to every operation contract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to update an existing webservice and add 2 parameters to every operation contract.
Is there a way to add these automatically by overloading a class or inherits from an interface?

To be clear on what i want, here is an exemple:
i have now

```
[OperationContract]
MyObject MyMethod(int parameter);
```

and i now need

```
[OperationContract]
MyObject MyMethod(string otherParameter, int parameter);
```

without having to rewrite every operations.

Comment: can you tell us more about the context of this new parameter?  what is it for?  could it change per call? if not, does it change per service or operation contract?

Comment: For details, i need to add identification parameters of the service customer without having to write it on every contract and call.

Comment: ok, so there is the potential to source this information from the request itself and inject it into the service constructor as a parameter.  The mechanism will depend on how your service is hosted.  How is your WCF service hosted? (IIS/ windows service etc) and what authentication protocol does it use?

Comment: ok. what means of authentication do you use?

Comment: i use windows authentication and need to add them into the SQL Server connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to add parameters to a method through inheritance. Furthermore, WCF methods [cannot be overloaded](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/09/21/overloading-methods-in-wcf.aspx), so adding a method with the same name but with the extra parameters is also not an option.

The easiest way is to update the interface (service contract) and its implementations (the actual services themselves) manually.

However, you can get really clever about this (probably not a good idea though) but WCF has a few extensibility points that you can use.

You can control how the messages are serialized/deserialized, you can specify how a particular operation is selected, in sum, you could achieve what you want without changing the contracts. However the effort would certainly be much more than manually updating the interface and implementation.

[**Here's**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx) a good resource that explains those extensibility points

If you just want to identify the user you can do that through OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext in your service method, [**this resource**](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/identity-securitycallcontext-in-wcf/) has an example of how you can achive that.

Comment: SO no hope from this side, i'll rewrite all. And from the calling part, can i add the parameters automatically or theres no hope too?

Comment: @Arngrim since you are changing the contract you'll have to update the client code as well.

Comment: I add a comment on the main post to add details about the context if you have an idea and/or a solution

Comment: Also next time you start by defining a service, you can consider to use datacontracts on custom types, that way if you need a new parameter you can put it in the base type of your type and then have specific types for your operations.

Comment: It solve a part of what i need (the username) but i also need the computer name of the customer but i'm not sure that part can be done in a web context.

Comment: @Arngrim In a web context I'm not sure how you could achieve that, sorry

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I put your answer as accepted for the first part.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to change the implementation of each operationContract using that additional parameter, it is not a big deal to change the signature.

If you are not going to use that parameter, what is the necessary in adding that parameter?

Answer (score -2):

Do you absolutely 'need' this parameter to be passed by the caller?

If not, you can use an IOC container to pass this to each WCF service via the constructor as it is instantiated.

To do this in Ninject you would register the following....

```
Bind<ISomeService>().To<MyWcfService>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("otherParameter", theParameterValue);
```

The example above assumes that the parameter being introduced does not change per call.

If it did change per call you can pass it a method instead of a variable, or use a lambda...

```
Bind<ISomeService>().To<MyWcfService>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("otherParameter", () => { /* TODO calculate value */ });
```

If you are new to IOC containers and dependency injection you can [read about them here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver).

I recommend [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) due to its simple API and [performance](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison).

Comment: The OP wants to change the operation contracts, not the service constructor

Comment: he may well 'assume' that he needs to change the operation contracts, as that can seem like the only obvious choice.  If the 'otherParameter' is something that doesnt need to be passed by the caller then its a valid solution.

Comment: Even if the OP takes the lambda approach, there's no way the parameter value can be different per operation contract.

Comment: why do you assume there is a requirement to change the parameter value per operation contract?